# ubuntu think my C/C++ source file is plain file

Tags: nautilus, mime-type

Today I suddenly find that when I create a C or C++ source code file like using vi or touch

```
touch test.c
```

The Ubuntu don't think it is source code file and recognize it as plain text. And when i use file command it shows:

```
test.c: empty
```

Write a simple program in it

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
  printf("hello world");
}
```

I use GCC to compile it,

```
gcc test.c -o test
```

then the plain text now can be recognized as C source file and the icon is changed to C source code file.

However, I get a sharedlib file instead of executable file.
It looks strange. In the past, when I create a .c/.cpp file, the system will correctly recognize its file type.How can I fix it?

Comment: As far as I know the `file` program has to read what is contained within the file to determine what type of file it is. Linux doesn't care what file extensions you use.  It is up to the individual applications like the file browsers, or compilers to care what the extension is.

Comment: BTW, `empty` does not mean `plain text`.  It is just an empty file.

Comment: @Terrance Got it. Do you have an idea about why my ubuntu can't recognize the file type correctly? It really bother me.

Comment: Are you only talking about the `file` application that you ran?  It does not recognize file extensions.  It is how the application was written.  You can take the same `test.c` file with the contents still in it and move the name to `test.txt` and file will still say that it is a `C source, ASCII text` type file.  However, gcc will not use the txt file and will throw an error stating that the file is not in the correct format even though the two files are identical in nature.  You could even take the same file and add a `+x` to it with `chmod` and now Linux will try to run it as executable.

Comment: By "The Ubuntu" I assume you mean the file manager, Nautilus.